# Django optimize complicated grouping count

Tags: django, django-models

I have the models below:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ....
    cases = models.ManyToMany('Case')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Case(models.Model):
    ....
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')

class Product(model.Model):
    ....
```

I want to get all the products (that are linked with an approved case) grouped by companies' active status. So, the result should be like:

```
{
    <Product: 1>: [12, 5], // 12 is the count of the active companies, and 5 is the non active companies
    <Product: 3>: [3, 4],
    <Product: 7>: [10, 2]
}
```

I have worked with the below approach, and it returned the correct result, but I want to optimize it.

```
companies = Company.objects.prefetch_related('cases').all()
products = {}
for i in companies:
    for c in i.cases.select_related('product').all():
        if c.is_approved == True:
            p = c.product
            if p not in products.keys():
                products[p] = [0, 0]
            if i.is_active == True:
                products[p][0] += 1
            elif i.is_active == False:
                products[p][0] += 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Product.objects.annotate(active_compagnies=Count("case__compagny_set", filter=Q(is_approved=True, compagny_set__is_active=True), distinct=True), inactive_compagnies=Count("case__compagny_set", filter=Q(is_approved=True, compagny_set__is_active=False), distinct=True))
```

This should yield your two numbers, in order to know the best way to yield an array, i would need a more precise use case (if this data is served by an API it could be a good idea to solve the array during the serialization)